# Not showing images on second frontend shop

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, store-view

We have 2 storeviews, everything is working fine on both storeviews except the product images on the second shop.

Main shop url: https://shop.diana-lys.aze.dk/default

Second shop url: https://shop.diana-lys.aze.dk/eur

On the backend the images are shown on both storeviews. And I have set the attributes as Global for all the images

On the main shop a image could be: https://shop.diana-lys.aze.dk/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/d80dba0dabe6c7def590d4d5d4c31073/2/2/22305084s_9.jpg

On the second shop, same product the image is: https://shop.diana-lys.aze.dk/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/201deb37a6bdbe2d27f8a762f254af4e/2/2/22305084s_9.jpg

It should be the same image. I am using Firebear to import the products from a CSV file. We are using the same template for both shops.

I have tried with deleting the var/cache - reindexing, clearing and flushing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below command:

```
php <magento install dir>/bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Sometimes you may need to re-build the product images cache after you import products.

This command will take long time for execution if you have large catalog.